# Узнать полный путь к базе данных

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Каким образом можно узнать **путь к файлам конкретной базы данных** POSTGESQL?

1. Я могу узнать путь к хранилищу "по-умолчанию"

   SHOW data_directory;

"C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.3/data"
2. Узнать список БД и их oid-ы:

```
SELECT datname,datdba FROM pg_database WHERE datname='persons' OR datname='mis'
```

"persons";16430
"mis";46521

Но папок с названиями 16430 или 46521 **НЕТ** в папке "C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/base/"

Причём, относительный путь к конкретной таблице узнать можно:

```
SELECT pg_relation_filepath('mis.mir.otdel');
```

"base/6377315/6377362"

(действительно,  файл C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/base/6377315/6377362 существует)

Comment: а зачем вам это нужно? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Например, перенести самую большую БД на другой диск и поставить символическую ссылку.